# Can I download Visible Body software?

Tags: 12.04

I'd like to download the Visible Body software

http://www.visiblebody.com/download_overview

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Will this download work?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't show that its available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, since it is not listed as an option for download. But you could try running it through wine or another windows emulator. I can't say as I am not familiar with the program